# List of coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, coordinate-systems

Maybe this is a silly question but I am a bit confused. When I have a list of coordinates that are presented in one line, do I write $(x,y)=\{(a,b),(c,d),(f,g)\}$ or $(x,y)=(a,b),(c,d),(f,g)$?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is incorrect, you can write $(x,y) \in \{(a,b), (c,d), (f,g)\}$ if you want, but you can't say it is equal to that set. Really any such expression is trying to abbreviate an expression like "for every ordered pair $(x,y) \in \{(a,b),(c,d),...\}$". The second way of writing it is an acceptable colloquial way of writing that, e.g. "for $(x,y) = (a,b), (c,d),(e,f)$ ...."